# Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: registry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert's altnames

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssl

I have a Ubuntu server running Apache Tomcat with SSL for a domain (e.g abc.xyz). In that server, I also set up Docker for deploying Next.js. However, when I build a container for a demo application, it shows error:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID
npm ERR! errno ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fnode failed, reason: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: registry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.abc.xyz, DNS:abc.xyz

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-11-06T15_27_49_018Z-debug.log
```

I tried many solutions like setting `strict-ssl=false`, setting registry (you can see it in my repository), changing DNS nameserver to OpenDNS but they don't work.

I also tried to run command `npm install` outside Docker and it still works.

Repository URL [here](https://gitlab.com/lioaslan/next-demo).

**Updated**: This error doesn't occur not only in Nodejs but also in Java. I built a Dockerfile that contains `RUN mvn package` and it shows the same error

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom: 
Certificate for <repo.maven.apache.org> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.abc.xyz, abc.xyz] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Why isn't `registry.npmjs.org` set as one of the certificate's altnames?

Comment: that's what makes me confused :)

Comment: Do you have any proxies involved? Seems like `registry.npmjs.org` is resolving to a wrong IP Address. Is `abc.xyz` your own domain? If it works on your host but not inside your docker image it oviously has to do something with your docker configuration or that particular image you are using.

Comment: No, I just run an Apache tomcat for Jenkins through port 8443. `abc.xyz` is an example domain. I bought SSL for my domain and configured it in Tomcat. Dockerfile [here](https://gitlab.com/lioaslan/next-demo/-/blob/main/Dockerfile). I tried to setup Tomcat and Jenkins, Docker, and build again in a empty Ubuntu image but nothing changes

Comment: Step 4/9 : RUN ping registry.npmjs.org
 ---> Running in 38af47a2751f
PING registry.npmjs.org (104.16.19.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 104.16.19.35 (104.16.19.35): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=1.75 ms

Comment: I think it shows correct IP

Comment: Yes, I was aware, that `abc.xyz` is just a placeholder for your real domain. But as the error message shows your own certificate, your HTTP traffic is seemingly going through some proxy which returns your own certificate instead of the server's certificate. Because if you go to `https://registry.npmjs.org` on your host machine, you will see it serves `npmjs.org`, `*.npmjs.org `and `sni.cloudflaressl.com` as alternative names. If you get different hostnames in your error, you are either connecting to the wrong server, or something in between (ie a proxy) is replacing the certificate ...

Comment: Yes the IP address seems correct. But PING works on another layer of the Network Protocol than HTTP, so even if you connect the correct server (and it seems, name resolution works ok) with PING, you still might have some HTTP-proxy tampering with your HTTP-Traffic

Comment: whether Tomcat work as a proxy? I just use Tomcat to run a war file of Jenkins. I checked carefully, no other proxy process is running.